# Error "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" on mysql queries from docker

Tags: mysql

I have a python script that runs 6 queries in mysql one after the other. One of the requests keeps getting a connection loss error. If this request is deleted, then the whole process ends successfully.
If you execute the full version of the script, but not in docker, then everything also ends with success.
Docker is installed on windows 10.
For the test, I asked a colleague to lift the container on his machine to Linux. As a result, the script ran successfully both in docker and outside of it.
I've already tried adding variables to mysql.connector.connect:
connect_timeout
buffered = True
consume_results = True
added

```
conn.reconnect (attempts = 50, delay = 1)
conn.ping (reconnect = True, attempts = 50)
cursor.execute ('SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME = 2880000')
cursor.execute ('SET SESSION interactive_timeout = 2880000')
```

Nothing helps.
If someone is faced with a similar problem, I will be glad to receive any information. Below is the docker-compose.yml code attached although it doesn't seem to matter.

```
version: '3'
services:
    redis:
        image: 'redis:5.0.5'
        restart: always
        # command: redis-server --requirepass redispass
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        restart: always
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
        # Uncomment these lines to persist data on the local filesystem.
        #     - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        # volumes:
        #     - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    webserver:
        build: ./docker/workflow
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
            - redis
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
            # - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
            # - REDIS_PASSWORD=redispass
        volumes:
            - ./container-data/airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            - ./:/app
            # Uncomment to include custom plugins
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3
    flower:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.4
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - redis
        environment:
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
            # - REDIS_PASSWORD=redispass
        ports:
            - "6666:6666"
        command: flower
    scheduler:
        build: ./docker/workflow
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - webserver
        volumes:
            - ./:/app
            - ./container-data/airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            # Uncomment to include custom plugins
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
            # - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
            # - REDIS_PASSWORD=redispass
        command: scheduler
    worker:
        build: ./docker/workflow
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - scheduler
        volumes:
            - ./:/app
            - ./container-data/airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            # Uncomment to include custom plugins
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
        environment:
            - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
            # - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
            # - REDIS_PASSWORD=redispass
        command: worker
```